# Docker Compose with PHP, MySQL, nginx connection issue

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, docker, docker-compose

I have problem to connect to MySQL container.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
    mysql:
        image: mysql:latest
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: JoeyW#1999
            MYSQL_DATABASE: wiput
            MYSQL_USER: web
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: Web#1234
        volumes:
            - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
        networks:
            - code-network
    php:
        image: wiput1999/php:latest
        volumes:
            - ./code:/code
        networks:
            - code-network
    nginx:
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
        volumes:
            - ./code:/code
            - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
            - /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
        networks:
            - code-network
networks:
    code-network:
        driver: bridge
```

PHP test script:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "JoeyW#1999";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=wiput", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

This script reponse me :

```
Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

What's wrong with my code? because I think It's should be fine

If anyone have a better solution Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `$servername = "localhost";` to `$servername = "mysql";`. Your mysql service isn't on the localhost of your webserver container. You should use the name of the service instead

Comment: Still have the same response